# Ошибка 429 при использовании BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Суть программы такова, я захожу на определенную страницу, получаю оттуда название товара и потом отправляю в гугл search запрос в котором написано название этого товара
(товар - стул, тогда запрос вида [https://www.google.com/search?q=стул](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB))
Но спустя пару дней тестирования и отладки программы гугл стал выдавать мне ошибку 429, что в таком случае делать?
Я пробовал добавлять time.sleep() между запросами, но не помогло. Еще пробовал подождать и какое-то время не запускать программу, однако это тоже не помогло. Подскажите, что в таком случае делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: в документации написано, что лимит стоит на сутки и в теле ошибки есть информация, сколько времени осталось ждать. Как вариант делайте через прокси запросы